# difference between scipy.ndimage.interpolate convolve and correlate

Tags: python, scipy

I'm just trying to get familiar with scipy.ndimage and I can't figure out how interpolate.convolve and interpolate.correlate are different.

```
In [24]: a
Out[24]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.],
       [  3.,   4.,   5.],
       [  6.,   7.,   8.],
       [  9.,  10.,  11.]])
In [25]: filt=array([[0,1,0],[1,2,1],[0,1,0]])
In [26]: convolve(a,weights=filt)
Out[26]: 
array([[  4.,   9.,  14.],
       [ 19.,  24.,  29.],
       [ 37.,  42.,  47.],
       [ 52.,  57.,  62.]])
In [27]: correlate(a,weights=filt)
Out[27]: 
array([[  4.,   9.,  14.],
       [ 19.,  24.,  29.],
       [ 37.,  42.,  47.],
       [ 52.,  57.,  62.]])
In [28]: correlate == convolve
Out[28]: False
```

Are they exactly the same?

Comment: [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) vs [correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_correlation)

Comment: Try an asymmetric `filt`, and you'll see the difference.

Comment: [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Comparison_convolution_correlation.svg) pretty much explains everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

convolution [f(x), g(x)] = correlation [f(x), g(-x)]

[Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) is happens when you simply move a kernel over an image.

[Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) is a mathematical concept (also used in physics), playing a role for instance in [Fourier Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) or when calculating the [probability density of quantum mechanical particles/wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function).